# What is the scope of a namespace identifier?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

It seems that there is no clear definition over the *point of declaration*, *declarative region*, *scope* of **a namespace identifier**, except those of **an identifier inside a namespace**—according to the standard(§3.3.6/1).

> The declarative region of a namespace-definition is its namespace-body. The potential scope denoted by
>   an original-namespace-name is the concatenation of the declarative regions established by each of the
>   namespace-definitions in the same...

Although the standard indeed talks about those of a *declaration*—a *namespace-definition* is declaration, that is not applicable to the case of namespace-definition because it has no *declarator*, nor *initializer*—according to the standard(§3.3.2/1).

> The point of declaration for a name is immediately after **its complete declarator** (Clause 8) and before **its
>   initializer** (if any), except as noted below...

Then, how can I determine those of a namespace identifier?

Comment: I'm wondering what problem you are worried about. Can you give an example where it would matter?

Comment: @5gon12eder I just want to make things clear. That's all.

Comment: @5gon12eder: This question has the language-lawyer tag. The problem he's worried about is clearly the standard and the wording thereof.

Comment: @NicolBolas Sure, but if there is no imaginable code sample where it would make a difference, what would be the significance of this? Would it even be a well-defined problem? Anyway, I was just curios what the OP might have had in mind.

Comment: **plus 1** because inspection of the standard didn't yield any clear answer.

Comment: @5gon12eder Is it permissible to use a namespace identifier before it's declared? We never know if **those** of a namespace identifier isn't clearly defined.

Comment: So you mean whether something like `{ using namespace X; } namespace X { }` would be allowed? I vaguely remember there was a similar discussion on the ioscpp mailing list recently.

Comment: So, we have **[basic.namespace] 7.3\1** mentioned by Francis Cugler in his answer below. But **3.3.1\1** claims that any name is introduced in some declarative region. So namespace name should be introduced in some declarative region, which is also a namespace by the rule **7.3\1**. But... Then we have this dubious rule **3.3.6\1**, which claims interesting thing, isn't it? I think, it is a miswording.

Comment: It looks like point of declaration is left undefined for namespace names, which is probably an omission in the standard.

Comment: @n.m. And that too : D What is a declarator for a namespace? I know there are declarations, but namespace declaration may be split on parts **(7.3\1)**... Poor compiler writers.

Comment: @EugeneZavidovsky "Declarative region" is not a problem. It's always an enclosing namespace. "Scope" is a problem. Scope starts at the point of declaration, which is not defined for namespace names.

Comment: @EugeneZavidovsky There's no declarator, which is by itself not a problem (e.g. classes have no declarators and it's OK).

Comment: @n.m. Oh, well. It seems that you are right. It was a problem for me to understand, what declarative region they implied in **7.3\1**: that, which is named by a namespace being introduced, or that, where it is introduced. Thank you for explanation! And, yeah, scope of a namespace is the problem then... Point of declaration for a namespace, precisely.

Comment: @n.m I came to the same conclusion; however If I had determine what the point of declaration is for named namespaces I would have to suggest directly after its identifier and before its scope. Which in essence is the space between the qualifying name, declaration, definition and the opening brace.

Comment: The behavior of how the scope or the declarative region of a Namespace can be defined or declared is quite different than that of a function or class.

Comment: Think of a namespace as Chain Stores. There are many different chain stores such as Staples, Best Buy, Home Depot, etc., These would be your namespaces, where each of the individual stores would be separate translation units, and the products, equipment and employees would be its members. The entire franchise or corporation consist of the entire namespace. The name above the door is its identifier(definition), and the door's threshold is the open brace. As you look past the sign (namespace) and just before you walk into the door would be the Point of Declaration for a namespace if it had one.

Comment: (...continued) It is magic for it doesn't exist yet it is there; just like the automatic doors that open for you.

Comment: ...There is another mistake I made in the previous posts. The rule **7.3.1\2** was supposed to claim, I think, that a _namespace-name_ should be introduced not in any declarative region, but only those, which are namespaces (there are many kinds of declarative regions, for instance **3.3.3\1**). So the words "a namespace scope" and "a namespace" imply the same thing, don't they?

Comment: @EugeneZavidovsky You can imply that, since this statement came right from the standard: The outermost declarative region of a translation unit is a namespace.

Comment: I would like to add to the Chain Store analogy; think of the global scope which is an empty namespace would be the planet or the world itself!

Comment: @FrancisCugler Analogies no more! Moders are out there!

Comment: @n.m. You have said everything I wanted to say... :)

Answer (score 3):

From the text you quoted from the standard, my interpretation would be that you have answered your own question.

As you say, a namespace cannot have a complete declarator, since an additional declarative region for it can be created in any compilation unit (i.e. source file or header included by that source file) for any namespace `X` by `namespace X { <new names within this declarative region> }`.

Since there can never be a complete declaration of a namespace, there can never be a point of declaration for a namespace.    Since there is no point of declaration, there is no such thing as a namespace identifier, and no such thing as a scope of one.

Which means that a namespace is just a label which can be part of an identifier.   `istream` is an identifier within namespace `std`, the complete name of that identifier (as referenced from code outside a declarative region of namespace `std`) is `std::istream`.    All the `using namespace std;` does is, when trying to find a match for a potential identifier `foo` is tell the compiler to look within namespace `std` (or the declarative regions it has visibility of) for an identifier named `foo` which will be a candidate match.   [Which is why `using namespace` for multiple namespaces can result in ambiguity, if more than one namespace contains the same identifier].

Comment: "std is not an identifier" Of course it is; see productions in 7.3.1 and 7.3.2.

Comment: The definition, declaration and its identifier are all one in the same, just as its declarative region and scope are one in the same that can span across multiple translation units.

Comment: You are saying that std is not an identifier. Then how does the compiler use it in a look up table for its resolution or visibility? Also can you not do this `namespace myNamespace = std { ....  }` ?

Comment: OK;  removed the text "`std` is not an identifer.

Comment: @Peter **I really love your answer** but without any reference I cannot accept it. I want to note it's **not** that your answer is insufficient. Thank you for such a great interpretation.

Comment: That's no problem, Il-seob.  The only references in my post are to yours.  The rest was my interpretation, for which no reference is needed, but which folks may choose to contest.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your initial assumption:

> It seems that there is no clear definition over the point of
>   declaration, declarative region, scope of a namespace identifier,
>   except those of an identifier inside a namespace—according to the
>   standard(§3.3.6/1).

I was reading this from the standard found at [open-std.org/pdf](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4527.pdf)

> 3.3.6 Namespace scope [basic.scope.namespace] 1 The declarative region of a namespace-definition is its namespace-body. Entities declared in
>   a namespace-body are said to be members of the namespace, and names
>   introduced by these declarations into the declarative region of the
>   namespace are said to be member names of the namespace. A namespace
>   member name has namespace scope. Its potential scope includes its
>   namespace from the name’s point of declaration (3.3.2) onwards; and
>   for each using-directive (7.3.4) that nominates the member’s
>   namespace, the member’s potential scope includes that portion of the
>   potential scope of the using-directive that follows the member’s point
>   of declaration. [ Example:

```
namespace N { 
    int i; 
    int g(int a) { return a; } 
    int j(); 
    void q(); 
} 

namespace { int l=1; } 
// the potential scope of l is from its point of declaration 
// to the end of the translation unit 

namespace N { 
    int g(char a) { // overloads N::g(int)
        return l+a; // l is from unnamed namespace 
    } 

    int i; // error: duplicate definition 
    int j(); // OK: duplicate function declaration

    int j() { // OK: definition of N::j() 
        return g(i); // calls N::g(int)
    } 
    int q(); // error: different return type 
}
```

> —end example ]

Which lead me to read the following sections:

**3.3**

> 3.3 Scope [basic.scope]
>   3.3.1 Declarative regions and scopes [basic.scope.declarative] 1 Every name is introduced in some portion of program text called a
>   declarative region, which is the largest part of the program in which
>   that name is valid, that is, in which that name may be used as an
>   unqualified name to refer to the same entity. In general, each
>   particular name is valid only within some possibly discontiguous
>   portion of program text called its scope. To determine the scope of a
>   declaration, it is sometimes convenient to refer to the potential
>   scope of a declaration. The scope of a declaration is the same as its
>   potential scope unless the potential scope contains another
>   declaration of the same name. In that case, the potential scope of the
>   declaration in the inner (contained) declarative region is excluded
>   from the scope of the declaration in the outer (containing)
>   declarative region.
>   2 [ Example: in

```
int j = 24;
int main() {
    int i = j, j;
    j = 42;
}
```

> the identifier j is declared twice as a name (and used twice). The
>   declarative region of the first j includes the entire example. The
>   potential scope of the first j begins immediately after that j and
>   extends to the end of the program, but its (actual) scope excludes the
>   text between the , and the }. The declarative region of the second
>   declaration of j (the j immediately before the semicolon) includes all
>   the text between { and }, but its potential scope excludes the
>   declaration of i. The scope of the second declaration of j is the same
>   as its potential scope. —end example ] 3 The names declared by a
>   declaration are introduced into the scope in which the declaration
>   occurs, except that the presence of a friend specifier (11.3), certain
>   uses of the elaborated-type-specifier (7.1.6.3), and using-directives
>   (7.3.4) alter this general behavior. 4 Given a set of declarations in
>   a single declarative region, each of which specifies the same
>   unqualified name, (4.1) — they shall all refer to the same entity, or
>   all refer to functions and function templates; or (4.2) — exactly one
>   declaration shall declare a class name or enumeration name that is not
>   a typedef name and the other declarations shall all refer to the same
>   variable or enumerator, or all refer to functions and function
>   templates; in this case the class name or enumeration name is hidden
>   (3.3.10). [ Note: A namespace name or a class template name must be
>   unique in its declarative region (7.3.2, Clause 14). —end note ] §
>   3.3.1 38
>
> c ISO/IEC N4527 [ Note: These restrictions apply to the declarative
>   region into which a name is introduced, which is not necessarily the
>   same as the region in which the declaration occurs. In particular,
>   elaborated-type-specifiers (7.1.6.3) and friend declarations (11.3)
>   may introduce a (possibly not visible) name into an enclosing
>   namespace; these restrictions apply to that region. Local extern
>   declarations (3.5) may introduce a name into the declarative region
>   where the declaration appears and also introduce a (possibly not
>   visible) name into an enclosing namespace; these restrictions apply to
>   both regions. —end note ] 5 [ Note: The name lookup rules are
>   summarized in 3.4. —end note ]

**3.1**

> 3.1 Declarations and definitions [basic.def] 1 A declaration (Clause 7) may introduce one or more names into a translation unit or
>   redeclare names introduced by previous declarations. If so, the
>   declaration specifies the interpretation and attributes of these
>   names. A declaration may also have effects including: (1.1) — a static
>   assertion (Clause 7), (1.2) — controlling template instantiation
>   (14.7.2), (1.3) — use of attributes (Clause 7), and (1.4) — nothing
>   (in the case of an empty-declaration). § 3.1 33
>
> c ISO/IEC N4527 2 A declaration is a definition unless it declares a
>   function without specifying the function’s body (8.4), it contains the
>   extern specifier (7.1.1) or a linkage-specification25 (7.5) and
>   neither an initializer nor a functionbody, it declares a static data
>   member in a class definition (9.2, 9.4), it is a class name
>   declaration (9.1), it is an opaque-enum-declaration (7.2), it is a
>   template-parameter (14.1), it is a parameter-declaration (8.3.5) in a
>   function declarator that is not the declarator of a
>   function-definition, or it is a typedef declaration (7.1.3), an
>   alias-declaration (7.1.3), a using-declaration (7.3.3), a
>   static_assert-declaration (Clause 7), an attributedeclaration (Clause
>   7), an empty-declaration (Clause 7), a using-directive (7.3.4), an
>   explicit instantiation declaration (14.7.2), or an explicit
>   specialization (14.7.3) whose declaration is not a definition. [
>   Example: all but one of the following are definitions:

```
int a; // defines a
extern const int c = 1; // defines c
int f(int x) { return x+a; } // defines f and defines x
struct S { int a; int b; }; // defines S, S::a, and S::b
struct X { // defines X
    int x; // defines non-static data member x
    static int y; // declares static data member y
    X(): x(0) { } // defines a constructor of X
};
int X::y = 1; // defines X::y
enum { up, down }; // defines up and down
namespace N { int d; } // defines N and N::d
namespace N1 = N; // defines N1
X anX; // defines anX
```

> whereas these are just declarations:

```
extern int a; // declares a
extern const int c; // declares c
int f(int); // declares f
struct S; // declares S
typedef int Int; // declares Int
extern X anotherX; // declares anotherX
using N::d; // declares d
```

> —end example ] 3 [ Note: In some circumstances, C++ implementations
>   implicitly define the default constructor (12.1), copy constructor
>   (12.8), move constructor (12.8), copy assignment operator (12.8), move
>   assignment operator (12.8), or destructor (12.4) member functions.
>   —end note ] [ Example: given

```
#include <string>

struct C {
    std::string s; // std::string is the standard library class (Clause 21)
};

int main() {
    C a;
    C b = a;
    b = a;
}
```

> the implementation will implicitly define functions to make the
>   definition of C equivalent to 25) Appearing inside the braced-enclosed
>   declaration-seq in a linkage-specification does not affect whether a
>   declaration is a definition. § 3.1 34
>
> c ISO/IEC N4527

```
struct C {
    std::string s;
    C() : s() { }
    C(const C& x): s(x.s) { }
    C(C&& x): s(static_cast<std::string&&>(x.s)) { }
        // : s(std::move(x.s)) { }
    C& operator=(const C& x) { s = x.s; return *this; }
    C& operator=(C&& x) { s = static_cast<std::string&&>(x.s); return *this; }
        // { s = std::move(x.s); return *this; }
    ~C() { }
};
```

> —end example ] 4 [ Note: A class name can also be implicitly declared
>   by an elaborated-type-specifier (7.1.6.3). —end note ] 5 A program is
>   ill-formed if the definition of any object gives the object an
>   incomplete type (3.9).

Then you precede to state:

> Although the standard indeed talks about those of a declaration—a
>   namespace-definition is declaration, that is not applicable to the
>   case of namespace-definition because it has no declarator, nor
>   initializer—according to the standard(§3.3.2/1).

Then I read this:

> 3.3.2 Point of declaration [basic.scope.pdecl] 1 The point of declaration for a name is immediately after its complete declarator
>   (Clause 8) and before its initializer (if any), except as noted below.
>   [ Example:

```
unsigned char x = 12;
{ unsigned char x = x; }
```

> Here the second x is initialized with its own (indeterminate) value.
>   —end example ]

and then you quote this:

> The point of declaration for a name is immediately after its complete
>   declarator (Clause 8) and before its initializer (if any), except as
>   noted below...

I finally read this:

> 8 Declarators [dcl.decl] 1 A declarator declares a single variable,
>   function, or type, within a declaration. The init-declarator-list
>   appearing in a declaration is a comma-separated sequence of
>   declarators, each of which can have an initializer.
>   init-declarator-list: init-declarator init-declarator-list ,
>   init-declarator init-declarator: declarator initializeropt 2 The three
>   components of a simple-declaration are the attributes (7.6), the
>   specifiers (decl-specifier-seq; 7.1) and the declarators
>   (init-declarator-list). The specifiers indicate the type, storage
>   class or other properties of the entities being declared. The
>   declarators specify the names of these entities and (optionally)
>   modify the type of the specifiers with operators such as * (pointer
>   to) and () (function returning). Initial values can also be specified
>   in a declarator; initializers are discussed in 8.5 and 12.6. 3 Each
>   init-declarator in a declaration is analyzed separately as if it was
>   in a declaration by itself.100 4 Declarators have the syntax
>   declarator: ptr-declarator noptr-declarator parameters-and-qualifiers
>   trailing-return-type ptr-declarator: noptr-declarator ptr-operator
>   ptr-declarator noptr-declarator: declarator-id
>   attribute-specifier-seqopt noptr-declarator parameters-and-qualifiers
>   noptr-declarator [ constant-expressionopt] attribute-specifier-seqopt
>   ( ptr-declarator ) parameters-and-qualifiers: (
>   parameter-declaration-clause ) cv-qualifier-seqopt ref-qualifieropt
>   exception-specificationopt attribute-specifier-seqopt 100) A
>   declaration with several declarators is usually equivalent to the
>   corresponding sequence of declarations each with a single declarator.
>   That is T D1, D2, ... Dn; is usually equivalent to T D1; T D2; ... T
>   Dn; where T is a decl-specifier-seq and each Di is an init-declarator.
>   An exception occurs when a name introduced by one of the declarators
>   hides a type name used by the decl-specifiers, so that when the same
>   decl-specifiers are used in a subsequent declaration, they do not have
>   the same meaning, as in struct S ... ; S S, T; // declare two
>   instances of struct S which is not equivalent to struct S ... ; S S; S
>   T; // error Another exception occurs when T is auto (7.1.6.4), for
>   example: auto i = 1, j = 2.0; // error: deduced types for i and j do
>   not match as opposed to auto i = 1; // OK: i deduced to have type int
>   auto j = 2.0; // OK: j deduced to have type double Declarators 190
>
> c ISO/IEC N4527 trailing-return-type:
>   -> trailing-type-specifier-seq abstract-declaratoropt ptr-operator:
>   * attribute-specifier-seqopt cv-qualifier-seqopt & attribute-specifier-seqopt && attribute-specifier-seqopt
>   nested-name-specifier * attribute-specifier-seqopt cv-qualifier-seqopt
>   cv-qualifier-seq: cv-qualifier cv-qualifier-seqopt cv-qualifier: const
>   volatile ref-qualifier: & && declarator-id: ...opt id-expression 5 The
>   optional attribute-specifier-seq in a trailing-return-type appertains
>   to the indicated return type. The type-id in a trailing-return-type
>   includes the longest possible sequence of abstract-declarators. [
>   Note: This resolves the ambiguous binding of array and function
>   declarators. [ Example: auto f()->int(*)[4]; // function returning a
>   pointer to array[4] of int // not function returning array[4] of
>   pointer to int —end example ] —end note ]

You finally ask this:

> Then, how can I determine those of a namespace identifier?

Did you proceed to read this section?

> 7.3 Namespaces [basic.namespace] 1 A namespace is an optionally-named declarative region. The name of a namespace can be used to access
>   entities declared in that namespace; that is, the members of the
>   namespace. Unlike other declarative regions, the definition of a
>   namespace can be split over several parts of one or more translation
>   units. 2 The outermost declarative region of a translation unit is a
>   namespace; see 3.3.6.
>   7.3.1 Namespace definition [namespace.def] 1 The grammar for a namespace-definition is namespace-name: identifier namespace-alias
>   namespace-definition: named-namespace-definition
>   unnamed-namespace-definition nested-namespace-definition
>   named-namespace-definition: inlineopt namespace
>   attribute-specifier-seqopt identifier { namespace-body }
>   unnamed-namespace-definition: inlineopt namespace
>   attribute-specifier-seqopt{ namespace-body }
>   nested-namespace-definition: namespace enclosing-namespace-specifier
>   :: identifier { namespace-body } enclosing-namespace-specifier:
>   identifier enclosing-namespace-specifier :: identifier § 7.3.1 168
>
> c ISO/IEC N4527 namespace-body: declaration-seqopt 2 Every
>   namespace-definition shall appear in the global scope or in a
>   namespace scope (3.3.6). 3 In a named-namespace-definition, the
>   identifier is the name of the namespace. If the identifier, when
>   looked up (3.4.1), refers to a namespace-name (but not a
>   namespace-alias) introduced in the declarative region in which the
>   named-namespace-definition appears, the namespace-definition extends
>   the previously-declared namespace. Otherwise, the identifier is
>   introduced as a namespace-name into the declarative region in which
>   the named-namespace-definition appears. 4 Because a
>   namespace-definition contains declarations in its namespace-body and a
>   namespace-definition is itself a declaration, it follows that
>   namespace-definitions can be nested. [ Example:

```
namespace Outer {
    int i;
    namespace Inner {
        void f() { i++; } // Outer::i
        int i;
        void g() { i++; } // Inner::i
    }
}
```

> —end example ]
>   5 The enclosing namespaces of a declaration are those namespaces in
>   which the declaration lexically appears, except for a redeclaration of
>   a namespace member outside its original namespace (e.g., a definition
>   as specified in 7.3.1.2). Such a redeclaration has the same enclosing
>   namespaces as the original declaration. [ Example:

```
namespace Q {
    namespace V {
        void f(); // enclosing namespaces are the global namespace, Q, and Q::V
        class C { void m(); };
    }
    void V::f() { // enclosing namespaces are the global namespace, Q, and Q::V
        extern void h(); // ... so this declares Q::V::h
    }
    void V::C::m() { // enclosing namespaces are the global namespace, Q, and Q::V
    }
}
```

> —end example ] 6 If the optional initial inline keyword appears in a
>   namespace-definition for a particular namespace, that namespace is
>   declared to be an inline namespace. The inline keyword may be used on
>   a namespacedefinition that extends a namespace only if it was
>   previously used on the namespace-definition that initially declared
>   the namespace-name for that namespace. 7 The optional
>   attribute-specifier-seq in a named-namespace-definition appertains to
>   the namespace being defined or extended. 8 Members of an inline
>   namespace can be used in most respects as though they were members of
>   the enclosing namespace. Specifically, the inline namespace and its
>   enclosing namespace are both added to the set of associated namespaces
>   used in argument-dependent lookup (3.4.2) whenever one of them is, and
>   a usingdirective (7.3.4) that names the inline namespace is implicitly
>   inserted into the enclosing namespace as for an unnamed namespace
>   (7.3.1.1). Furthermore, each member of the inline namespace can
>   subsequently be partially specialized (14.5.5), explicitly
>   instantiated (14.7.2), or explicitly specialized (14.7.3) as though it
>   were a member of the enclosing namespace. Finally, looking up a name
>   in the enclosing namespace via § 7.3.1 169
>
> c ISO/IEC N4527 explicit qualification (3.4.3.2) will include members
>   of the inline namespace brought in by the using-directive even if
>   there are declarations of that name in the enclosing namespace. 9
>   These properties are transitive: if a namespace N contains an inline
>   namespace M, which in turn contains an inline namespace O, then the
>   members of O can be used as though they were members of M or N. The
>   inline namespace set of N is the transitive closure of all inline
>   namespaces in N. The enclosing namespace set of O is the set of
>   namespaces consisting of the innermost non-inline namespace enclosing
>   an inline namespace O, together with any intervening inline
>   namespaces. 10 A nested-namespace-definition with an
>   enclosing-namespace-specifier E, identifier I and namespace-body B is
>   equivalent to namespace E { namespace I { B } }
>   [ Example:

```
namespace A::B::C {
    int i;
}
```

> The above has the same effect as:

```
namespace A {
    namespace B {
        namespace C {
            int i;
        }
    }
}
```

> —end example ]

I think the lines of importance that answers your question is found from its definition 7.3 - 1 & 2 and 7.3.1 - 2,3 & 4. Provided you are working with a named namespace and you already understand scope, translation unit, declaration, definition and declarative space. There is no mention of a  declarator of a name space in the declarator section because it is listed in the declaration section under the namespace section because the named namespace or its definition is its declaration, thus the identifier is the name of the namespace itself or its definition - declaration.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. Indeed, the standard does specify the _declarative region_ of a namespace identifier. However, I still don't see where the _scope_ and _point of declaration_ of a namespace identifier are defined.

Comment: The scope of the name space is the declarative region which consists of the entire namespace. The point of declaration should be immediately after its definition declaration: `namespace std {  ...  }` the identifier is std and its scope resides in the global space and any declaration within reside within `std::` the point of declaration in this case because it is a name space should follow immediately after the identifier std.  Think of this as well you can have a separate scope by just using `{  code here  }` that has its own translation unit without any qualifying name.

Comment: (...continued) Section 3.3 covers Scope within this 3.3.1 pertains to Declarative Regions & Scopes, 3.3.2 covers point of declaration. Section 3.3.3 covers Block Scope and section 3.3.6 covers Namespace Scope.

Comment: (...continued) Think of a global function declared as `foo()`, you can use the scope resolution operator to access the global scope with `::foo()` if you are already within a defined name space that also has  `name::foo()` and you want to access the global version of `foo()` This has to deal with Scope and the Scope Resolution Operator. There is no initializer because the definition and declaration of a namespace is the same and the point of declaration immediately follows its first identifier which is its name.

Comment: (...continued) Also the scope of the name space is its entire body or declarative region which can span multiple blocks if the qualifying name matches and resides at the same level of the translation unit.

Comment: I can add another answer to try to explain this in a simple way, and leave this answer as the reference to the standard.

Comment: Most of the above governs the declarative region between the braces of `namespace foo { ... }`, and hardly anything governs the name `foo` itself.

Comment: My last part of the continued comment I got ahead of myself and wanted to edit it but now it won't let me; what I should of said was this: Also the scope of the name space is its entire body or declarative region which can span multiple blocks and files if the qualifying name matches, It can reside or span across multiple translation units.

Comment: @n.m the global scope does within each translation unit and even across multiple translation units. The outermost declarative region of a translation unit is a namespace. A namespace can be left blank without an identifier such as you see with the global scope resolution operator `::somefunc()`

Comment: This question is specifically about the scope of the namespace identifier, not the scope associated with the namespace itself. I don't see how identifiers that are not namespace identifiers, or namespaces without identifiers, are relevant to this discussion. Clearly the intent of the standard is to make the scope start right after the identifier of the original namespace definition, however, there's no wording to this effect.

Comment: @n.m. true but if you read the 2nd or 3rd page down; it is still a draft and says that it isn't complete and has many errors! LOL!

Comment: @n.m. also that is the point of a namespace because it is a space that is named or declared by its identifier and consists of all of its members! For example std is the identifier, std::string is a string object that is within the namespace or a part of it. The scope of the identifier either resides at the global scope or within another namespace! `std` resides at the global scope its identifier is globally defined!

Comment: @FrancisCugler What should that mean? And, please, limit yourself to quoting the _relevant_ parts of the normative, not whole paragraphs, maybe by emboldening them as well.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to break this down into parts based on the misunderstanding of the op.

He stated:

> It seems that there is no clear definition over the point of
>   declaration, declarative region, scope of a namespace identifier

```
// File A.h
namespace foo {        // Resides At Global Scope
    // some code here.
    void bar();        // Resided At foo:: Scope
}

// File A.cpp
namespace foo {
    // some more code here
    void bar() { 
        std::cout << "Hell World" << std::endl; 
    }
}
```

Here the declarative region spans multiple files for `foo` its definition and declaration is `foo` and `foo` is its identifier. Since this is a named namespace there is no declarator as you would see with a variable, function or type as defined in section 8.1

> A declarator declares a single variable, function, or type, within a
>   declaration

And there is no initializer either since it is a namespace. It is a declarative region that has scope.

And what I believe that the op is asking is this:

> Then, how can I determine those of a namespace identifier?

The namespace identifier is the name of the namespace which is also its definition and declaration. In a sense all 3 are one and the same, and the declarative region of a namespace and its scope is one and the same.

No, the standard doesn't draw a clear picture of the point of declaration for a namespace because it refers to the use of a declator which a namespace doesn't have. In some cases a namespace can be initialized by another namespace upon its definition - declaration as in: Typically an alias!

```
namespace someLongName{
}

namespace shortVersion = someLongName {
}
```

Where the point of declaration is found in 3.3.2.1, If you continue through this section in secession it moves on to Block Scope, Function Prototype Scope, Function Scope, Namespace Scope, Class Scope, Enumeration Scope, Template Parameter Scope, however if you refer back to 3.1 under definitions of Declarations and Definitions; a name space is defined and not declared, but in section 3.3.6

> The declarative region of a namespace-definition is its
>   namespace-body. Entities declared in a namespace-body are said to be
>   members of the namespace, and names introduced by these declarations
>   into the declarative region of the namespace are said to be member
>   names of the namespace. A namespace member name has namespace scope.
>   Its potential scope includes its namespace from the name’s point of
>   declaration (3.3.2) onwards; and for each using-directive (7.3.4) that
>   nominates the member’s namespace, the member’s potential scope
>   includes that portion of the potential scope of the using-directive
>   that follows the member’s point of declaration.

and

7.3 1 & 2

> 7.3 Namespaces [basic.namespace] 1 A namespace is an optionally-named declarative region. The name of a namespace can be used to access
>   entities declared in that namespace; that is, the members of the
>   namespace. Unlike other declarative regions, the definition of a
>   namespace can be split over several parts of one or more translation
>   units. 2 The outermost declarative region of a translation unit is a
>   namespace; see 3.3.6.

and

7.3.1 2-4

> 2 Every namespace-definition shall appear in the global scope or in a
>   namespace scope (3.3.6).
>   3 In a named-namespace-definition, the identifier is the name of the
>   namespace. If the identifier, when looked up (3.4.1), refers to a
>   namespace-name (but not a namespace-alias) introduced in the
>   declarative region in which the named-namespace-definition appears,
>   the namespace-definition extends the previously-declared namespace.
>   Otherwise, the identifier is introduced as a namespace-name into the
>   declarative region in which the named-namespace-definition appears.
>   4 Because a namespace-definition contains declarations in its
>   namespace-body and a namespace-definition is itself a declaration, it
>   follows that namespace-definitions can be nested.

Here I'll try to suggest even without a clear definition that the point of declaration for a namespace is immediately after its identifier - definition - declaration!

```
namespace /*keyword*/ std /*definition, declaration, identifier*/ (point of declaration) { /*beginning of declarative region & scope*/  
    .... // some code

} // End of declarative region or scope until another matching identifier at same level of scope is found. 
  // And this can span multiple translations units.
```

I hope this clears up the confusion.

Comment: I don't think the declarative region and scope of a namespace identifier is same...

Comment: @Il-seobBae I think within the context of a namespace; it can be considered the same. The declarative region starts after its identifier, and that is exactly when the scope begins. The maybe some subtle differences; but the two of the are mutually the same. I don't know if this would be an appropriate analogy or not, but I'm thinking that the declarative region of a namespace would be a person's property, where the scope would be the yard, and any structures within it. The fence assuming there is one determines the region, and the gate lets you access its scope.

Answer (score 0):

[P1787R6](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2020/p1787r6.html) addresses this as part of regularizing the name-lookup rules in general: now [basic.scope.scope] defines general terms like "target scope" that establish the context for a *namespace-definition* (and [basic.namespace.general]/3 addresses the special case of the global namespace), and [basic.scope.pdecl]/14 specifically addresses the locus (which replaced "point of declaration") for a namespace.